# How to pass data from one activity to another in Android application

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to create simple app where you type your data in one activity by editText and it's shown in another in TextView. But i really don't know how to make it work. As you can see this is simple code but right now when i click submit nothing happens on another activity.
this is first activty

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
    fun switchToActivity (view: View){
        val myIntent = Intent(this, Main2Activity::class.java)
        startActivity(myIntent)
    }
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int,
                                  resultCode: Int,
                                  myInten: Intent?) {
        var text2 = myInten?.getStringExtra("text")
        textView.setText(text2)
    }
}
```

And this is second

```
class Main2Activity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)
    }
    fun buttonListener (view: View){
        var text = editText.text.toString()

        val myIntent = Intent()
        myIntent.putExtra("textView", text)
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, myIntent)
        finish()
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.dev2qa.com/passing-data-between-activities-android-tutorial/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your code.

First, to receive result from another activity, you must use [startActivityForResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) instead.

```
fun switchToActivity (view: View){
    val myIntent = Intent(this, Main2Activity::class.java)
    startActivityForResult(myIntent)
}
```

Second, you must use the same key when saving and retrieving result.

```
var text2 = myInten?.getStringExtra("textView")
```

Put it together.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun switchToActivity (view: View){
        val myIntent = Intent(this, Main2Activity::class.java)
        startActivityForResult(myIntent)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int,
                                  resultCode: Int,
                                  myInten: Intent?) {
        var text2 = myInten?.getStringExtra("textView")
        textView.setText(text2)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use: `startActivityForResult(myIntent)` 
instead of: `startActivity(myIntent)`